# sqlite3 returns a syntax error on a user function

Tags: sqlite

In a C program using sqlite3 I created a user function:

```
        rc= sqlite3_create_function                                                 
(db,                  /*database*/                                          
 "dtst",              /*SQL name*/                                          
 1,                   /*number of arguments*/                               
 SQLITE_UTF8,         /*text encoding*/                                     
 NULL,                 /*pointer*/                                          
 cdtst,               /*implementing function*/                             
 NULL,                                                                      
 NULL                                                                       
);
```

I got SQLITE_OK as the return code.

I then issued

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2
(db,
"DELETE FROM moz_cookies WHERE dtst(baseDomain)",
35,
&stmt,
NULL);

This fails, with sqlite_errmsg: near "(": syntax error.  According to
https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html
this should be a valid expr.

Comment: What's the length of the query string? What are you telling sqlite its length is?

Comment: Hint: Use `-1` for the length of a normal C string argument for sqlite to figure it out itself.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem